# Kill all process of particular user in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, process

How to kill all process of one user?

When I make `ps aux` I obtain a list of process with several users, and I want to kill all process of user `name1`, for example. What's a command to do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: If the users are real persons this probably isn't a good idea.
I also think you want to kill processes to save time. This is a very bad idea.
For instance, the services in Ubuntu can be stopped using `sudo service the-service-name stop`. Killing processes may left corrupted files, databases, etc.

Answer (score 36):

In this case, it's pretty simple, you can use `killall` to kill, or send any other signal, to a bunch of processes at once. One of the "filtering" options is the owner: `killall --user name1`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `--user` argument, thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that `killall` in e.g Solaris Unix kills *all* running processes it can! See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall

Comment: This essentially logged off on ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 26):

Adding another option because nobody has mentioned it, and I don't like `killall` (using it on solaris can cause disaster).

`pkill` is more portable

```
pkill -u username
```

Comment: I don't find `killall` in Ubuntu, but `pkill` is already installed.

Comment: Didn't see `killall` on a CentOS machine, but I've always seen `pkill` on the machines I've used. This is probably the more portable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install `slay`:

aptitude install slay

Then issue `slay some-user`.

Be aware that if you kill off stuff for users you don't know the purpose for, you may render your machine unusable (until you restart).

If you really don't want to install slay:

```
ps -e -o user,pid | grep '^some-user ' | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill
```

(wait a bit)

```
ps -e -o user,pid | grep '^some-user ' | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Btw `awk` can grep something itself. No need to do `grep smth | awk`, cause you can use just `awk '/smth/{...}'` instead.

Comment: Here is a handy little function for you.   `killuser () { ps faux| awk -v user=$1 '$1==user{ system("kill -9 " $2) }' ;};`

Answer (score 1):

Identify the user, then `killall -user <username>`

They will have a bash (or similar) process associated with their login session killing that will kill their session.

To get a potentially better overview of what a user is doing - try `pstree <username>`

Comment: you need two dashes before user e.g. `--user`

Answer (score 1):

According to `man kill`:

```
kill -9 -1
    Kill all processes you can kill.
```

To apply it to a different user:

```
su -l username kill -9 -1
```